# Transform one to many data to columns

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, array-formulas, countif, google-sheets-query

Given this data:

[image: data source]

How do I transform it to look like this:

[image: target output]

There are two columns in the data source, `key` (`title`) and `value` (`responsibility`).
I need to transform it such that we have the `key` column (`title`) and then `n` columns where `n` is the highest number of `value` a key has, eg 3 in the picture above. Hence the columns should be:

`Title, 1, 2, 3`.

The values in each column `1, 2, 3` should be corresponding to values in the original data.

Any combination of formula is welcomed - I believe a combination of `Transpose` and/or `Query` (`pivot`) is appropriate but I cannot put it together.

In case this is too complex we can put an enumeration directly in the data source, but it would be nice to be able to have the formula work without it. Eg:

[image]

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1InYZ12VuuaSg0s3fiFTCx8BnwEan5JsqpsNBF973lWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:C}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A, COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A)), B:B}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That `COUNTIFS` formula is very clever, didn't think about that one. Google sheet's PIVOT SQL argument is very powerful but one must get used to it first... Many thanks. Works exactly as required.